# Is there a way to seamlessly sync the changes applied by a 'rails generator' command, on a remote ruby SDK environment?

Tags: rubymine

I setup a *remote SDK* using [this guide](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/RUBYDEV/Configuring+Remote+Interpreters), on a VMWare installation of Linux Mint. Everything seems to work fine, but whenever I generate something with the 'rails generate' command, the changes are only applied on the remote installation, at which point I have to synchronize it back to my *local* environment.

Is there any way that these changes are also applied locally at the same time? Just so I don't have to manually ask Rubymine to download the files that were changed?

In case you're wondering, I'm running Windows 7 x64 as the host machine. I'm trying to run a Rails application on a remote SDK, cause the gems it requires cannot be installed on Windows (lib8 and therubyracer). I figured that running it on a VM would work, which it does, except for this little details.

Also, I'm on Rubymine 6.3.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution per suggestion on another board to something similar applied in Vagrant, which is usually taken for granted: Shared Folders.

In my case, I'm using VMware to do the virtualization, and Shared Folders (though mentioned in the installation) aren't enabled by default.

All I had to do was create a Shared Folder out of my working directories, so that they'd always be synchronized with the VM itself, regardless of what I'm doing with them. This way, the rail generators of Rubymine would automatically transfer the files back to my Rubymine installation, or any other files, such as the database, if these had any changes applied.